# Basic Angular Routing Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Playing around with routing in AngularJS but I can't seem to get it working correctly. Trying to display some templates with different controllers for each, but it seems to only route to one of them.

Plunker link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/6nupjElxdxWR8Ov7f59n?p=preview

Here is the code:

**index.html**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#page1">Page1</a>
      <a href="#page2">Page2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="mainContent">
      <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: "base.html",
      controller: "homeController"
    })
    .when('/page1', {
      templateUrl: "page1.html",
      controller: "pageController"
    })
    .when('/page2', {
      templateUrl: "page2.html",
      controller: "pageController"
    });
});

app.controller('homeController', [
  '$scope',
  function homeController($scope) {
    console.log("Home");
  }
]);

app.controller('pageController', [
  '$scope',
  function pageController($scope) {
    console.log("Page");
  }
]);
```

**base.html**

```html
<div>Base</div>
```

**page1.html**

```html
<div>Page1</div>
```

**page2.html**

```html
<div>Page2</div>
```

Currently, it seems to only show the *base.html* template no matter what button is pressed.

Comment: is there anything on the console after you pressed the button?

Comment: Prints "home" anytime any button is pressed.

Comment: href="#page1" means scroll to element with id page1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a change in the default hash prefix:

> Due to aa077e8, the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang
>   URLs has changed from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!'). If your
>   application does not use HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that
>   do not support HTML5 mode, and you have not specified your own
>   hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a ! prefix. For
>   example, rather than mydomain.com/#/a/b/c the URL will become
>   mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c.
>
> If you actually want to have no hash-prefix, then you can restore the
>   previous behavior by adding a configuration block to you application:
>
> appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
>   $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); }]);
>   [Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)

So if you want to do it right and not change the version of angular you should:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the angular plugin. Try using

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

it worked correctly in your plunkr with 1.5.8

**EDIT**
it seems that you need to include ! before your path name in angular 1.6.0

```
<div id="menu">
      <a href="#!">Home</a>
      <a href="#!page1">Page1</a>
      <a href="#!page2">Page2</a>
</div>
```